# Julia | Error with Array Length when It Contains Division

Tags: julia

I have a problem in Julia, when the array length is variable and contains a division.

For example

```
length_of_array = n * (n + 1) / 2

array = Array{Float64,1}(length_of_array)
```

It returns an error related to "convert".

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1):

You can only use integers to index into arrays. Division, `/`, always returns floats, hence the error. Instead of `/`, use the `div` function. You can also use the unicode operator, `÷`, like this

```
length_of_array = (n * (n + 1)) ÷ 2
```

Comment: You should maybe go a bit further and explain that while `n*(n+1)/2` is mathematically an integer, programming-wise it is a float even though it is a "whole number"

Comment: You can use bitwise shift to divide by two (and floor)  ```(n * (n + 1))>>1```